Why constrain the unit type by a generic trait bound in a where clause (as in `where () : Trait<…>`)?
Today I've encountered a somewhat weird syntax - where ():
fn hex_primary<Stream, Context>(stream: Stream) -> Parsed<u8, Stream, Context>
where
  (): IntRadixParse<Stream, Context, u8>,
{
  uint_radix(2, Radix::HEX).parse(stream)
}

To me it looks like "bound on unit type (aka empty tuple)", but I can't make sense of it. The () type doesn't implement every trait by default, does it? Alas, the official documentation is too vague and not complete enough (while being overly verbose), and I couldn't find anything related in it.
The original RFC for where clause also mentions this syntax, but without proper explanation:
fn increment<T>(c: T) -> T
    where () : Add<int,T,T>
{
    1 + c
}

But besides that, I know that such bounds can be specified not only in trait generics.
So what is it, when is it used, why is it needed and which problems does it solve?

It should be noted the crate you are looking at is using unstable features and the RFC you are looking at includes plenty of pre-1.0 syntax.

@kmdreko Without a doubt! But alas, even the current edition of Rust by Example refers to it: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.82.0/rust-by-example/generics/where.html#see-also

@cher-nov I don't see where (): SomeTrait in the link you provided. It does use where Option<T>: Debug, which means what it says, the bound that is satisfied when Option<T> implements Debug. As the page points out, this kind of example is where you have to use where, as you cannot express a bound on Option<T> using the impl<T: SomeTrait> syntax.

@user4815162342 Read carefully: what I meant right here was the mention of RFC about where, provided at the bottom of this page.

In the code snippet, the where clause is used to narrow down the generic constraints. Instead of defining all the constraints, (): IntRadixParse<Stream, Context, u8> is used which means that whatever type Stream and Context have, they must follow the constraints of IntRadixParse.
The trait IntRadixParse is
pub trait IntRadixParse<Stream, Context, Token: 'static> = where
  Stream: Streaming,
  <Stream as Streaming>::Item: Into<u8>,
  Token: CheckedAdd + CheckedMul + CheckedSub + Zero + Copy + Debug,
  Context: Contexting<IntRadixAtom<Token>>,
  Context: Contexting<BaseAtom<u8>>,
  Context: Contexting<CoreAtom<Stream>>,
  Context: Contexting<UtilsAtom<Stream>>,
  u8: AsPrimitive<Token>;

Note: It uses the trait alias unstable feature
So to write the function without the weird unit constraint syntax, it would be something like
fn hex_primary<Stream, Context>(stream: Stream) -> Parsed<u8, Stream, Context>
where
  Stream: Streaming,
  <Stream as Streaming>::Item: Into<u8>,
  Context: Contexting<IntRadixAtom<u8>>,
  Context: Contexting<BaseAtom<u8>>,
  Context: Contexting<CoreAtom<Stream>>,
  Context: Contexting<UtilsAtom<Stream>>,
{
  uint_radix(2, Radix::HEX).parse(stream)
}

Note: In the function Token was replaced with u8
Another example:
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait A<T> = where T: B; // Similar to `IntRadixParse` which
                         // shows that T should implement B

/// trait B with a method a
trait B {
    fn a(self);
}

/// implemented for unit
impl B for () {
    fn a(self) {}
}

fn a<T>(a: T) where (): A<T> {
    a.a() // T gets inferred to have implemented B and `a()` can be called
}

fn main() {}


So it is only needed to deduplicate the code?

This answer doesn't really explain why where (): ... works here (or I don't get the explanation). Do these traits provide a blanket implementation that covers ()? Or are they specifically implemented for () to enable this kind of bound? How does providing the bound on () help in writing code that (presumably) doesn't operate on ()?

This syntax can also be used where some traits are not exported by the crate which needs to be used.

@user4815162342 T: IntRadixParse<U, V, W> is a generic bound which constrains its generic parameters U, V and W, but not the actual type T under consideration. So () is used as a dummy placeholder.

@user4815162342 Note that the implicit argument Self is not used on the right-hand side defining the trait alias, and that in (): Trait the () is the actual parameter instantiating the Self formal parameter. So there is no constraint on () here, it is just a dummy required by the syntax. It could be written in a less obtuse way if Self were used for say the Stream parameter.

@starblue trait Foo = Add<i32, Output = i32> also doesn't explicitly use Self yet the implementor is restricted.

@starblue I'm confused as to how Self enters the picture, given that hex_primary() is a function, not a method, and as such doesn't have a Self receiver. Also, in the new code example in the answer, B is implemented for ()

@user4815162342 Self enters the picture because a trait alias is a trait after all and traits are always implenented (or not) on a type that can be used as Self.  And similarly to the code in question the trait A of this answer is not implemented anywhere.

@cafce25 Thanks for the clarification, I think I get it now - the trait alias is defined in a slightly strange way without referring to some Self, which is why () can work as a placeholder, because it doesn't matter that () implements anything, just that the bounds from the alias are satisfied. This is incredibly confusing and I hope that pattern won't make it into the language along with the trait alias feature.

@cafce But it's used implicitly, the longer form would be trait Foo = where Self: Add<i32, Output = i32>.

(): IntRadixParse<Stream, Context, u8> really is a bound on the unit type. It works because the trait alias1 is defined like this:
pub trait IntRadixParse<Stream, Context, Token: 'static> = where
    …; // where bounds omitted for brevity

Take a special notice of the missing trait before where, there is no trait, so this is an alias for no trait whatsoever, given the conditions hold.
Every type fulfills "implements an empty set of traits" so the only thing that remains to be proven by the compiler is the bounds. So in short, because Self isn't referenced and there is no trait for it to fulfill, instead of unit () you could write any type there. When the type doesn't matter Rust programmers often use unit.
This makes trait aliases useful for abbreviating a bunch of bounds like explained in Timsib Adnap's answer


trait aliases are unstable


@cher-nov: You could see it as encapsulation, too, to a degree. Ie, it shouldn't matter to you what the exact bounds are, you just need to use the full package, which in turns allows the author to change the content of the package as necessary.
